# Trouble with serial communication

Tags: python, serial-port, embedded, pyserial

I’m stuck in a serial communication between Digi Xbee ConnectPort X3 and an embedded board. Digi Xbee is in python code. I’m sending the temperature and light sensor values from digi to the board in the form a packet:

```
Sync | Low Byte | High Byte | Data | Checksum
```

which the device accepts . I tested both the devices seperately . They work perfectly. I send data to the embedded board from my computer using `pyserial` it receives data perfectly (around 30 data). Then I checked whether the Digi is sending data perfectly using my computer in COM Port. But when I connect the Digi device to the board the digi sends very few data(1 to 3) ie I can debug the digi Xbee to an extend in which i see after sending few data the COM port of Digi Xbee closes .

I have added part of the source code of Digi Xbee for your understanding

```
open()

while True:
# Retrieve a sample reading from the LT

flushInput()

flushOutput()

io_sample = xbee.ddo_get_param(sensor_address, “is”)

light = parseIS(io_sample)["AI1"]

temp = parseIS(io_sample)["AI2"]

hum = parseIS(io_sample)["AI3"]

mVanalog = (float(temp) / 1023.0) * 1200.0

temp_C = (mVanalog – 500.0)/ 10.0 # – 4.0

lux = (float(light) / 1023.0) * 1200.0

print “hum:%f” %hum

sync=254

temp=round(temp_C,2)

light=round(lux,2)

no_temp = len(str(temp))

no_light = len(str(light))

total_length=no_temp+no_light+3+2

if total_length<256:

    low_byte=total_length

    high_byte=0

else:

  low_byte=total_length%256

  high_byte=high_byte/256

msg_id_low=0

msg_id_high=0

checksum=low_byte+high_byte+msg_id_low+msg_id_high+ord('#')+ord(':')+ord(',')

t=str(temp)

for c in t:

  if c == '.':

    checksum+=ord('.')

  else:

    checksum+=ord(c)

t=str(light)

for c in t:

  if c == '.':

    checksum+=ord('.')

  else:

    checksum+=ord(c)

checksum=256-(checksum%256)

if checksum == 256:

  checksum=0

print "Checksum Value after applying mod operator:%d" %checksum

packet=str(chr(254))+str(chr(low_byte))+str(chr(high_byte))+str(chr(msg_id_low))+str(chr(msg_id_high))+str('#')+str(temp)+str(':')+str(light)+str(',')+str(chr(checksum))


print "packet:%s" %packet

bytes_written = write(packet)

print "bytes_written : %s value : %s" %(bytes_written,packet)

time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: usually you do something like `my_serial.open()` and `my_serial.write()` ... your whitespace is incorrect as well ... btu that may just be because you pasted it incorrectly ...

Comment: Your code does not reveal any kind of communication between the two devices, it only shows some formatting and minor calculations. Can you *revise your post* and *include the necessary parts* (methods that use `serial.open()` e.g.), as well as leaving out the "business logic"?
Also, your code is unnecessarily winded: the first if-else statement can be collapsed to the body of the else statement, the next 2 for-loops can be reduced similarly and I'm fairly sure your last if-statement, together with the checksum calculation just above it, can be reduced too, but it depends on your application.